# Client Database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model

Can anyone direct me, or help me in setting up, whatever is required, and an ADO.net entity data model? What I need is, when my "ClientRegistrationWindow" pops up, to show the fields (name, phone number, etc) that are in the entity. It is pretty much what they have setup here [Microsoft MSDN Example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2/) but they provide the Entity, but I would like to make my own as it is a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd like to use the Entity Framework to do your data access?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399182.aspx

If so I'd suggest you start with the EF Quickstart provided by Microsoft.  If you run into specific issues you can ask more specific questions on here and I'm sure people can help you.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like just the thing I need